# can I refactor this code block to more extent. Need some suggestions

Tags: javascript, node.js

booolean ? function1(item,key):function2(item,key)

Based on the boolean it enters either of the function.So can this be refactored to more extent.Need suggestions.Thanks.

```
function1(item, key) {
    getInstance().updateItem(item, {
        flag1: "Fail",
        flag2: "Fail",
        flag3: "Fail",
        flag4: "Fail",
        flag5: "Fail",
        [key]: cipFailedFlags
     })
}

function2(item, key) {
    getInstance().updateItem(item, {
        [key]: cipFailedFlags
    })
}
```

can we eliminate the use of two functions and make it common? only the key-value pairs are extra in function1. I am just trying to reduce the redundancy here.

Comment: so pass in an object since that is all that is different. Not really a great question, might have been better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks buddy for the change . That isnt exactly an object if you look closely

Comment: Um, I see an object  that is different.... one has flags, one does not....

Comment: Couldn't you just pass the bool into a function, and it either sets the flags or it doesn't? Or just pass the object itself like epascarello suggests. It's not clear at all what the goal is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your boolean flag to the function as a parameter to build the correct object inside as follows:

```
function oneFn(item, key, flag) {
    getInstance().updateItem(item, Object.assign(
        { [key]: cipFailedFlags },
        flag ? { flag1: "Fail", flag2: "Fail", /* etc... */ } : {}
    ));
}
```

If you think the ternary operator makes it less readable, you can alter the function by using variables and `if` statements instead:

```
function oneFn(item, key, flag) {
    let config = { [key]: cipFailedFlags };
    if (flag) {
        config = { ...config, flag1: "Fail", flag2: "Fail", /* etc... */ };
    }
    getInstance().updateItem(item, config);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the function? Just use spread operator where you can add the items that are different in the object.

```
const params = myBool ?
  { a : 1, b: 2 } : {}
getInstance().updateItem(item, {
  ...params,
  [key]: cipFailedFlags
})
```

---

Example showing it running

```js
/* just a mock */
const getInstance = () => ({
  updateItem: (a, b, c) => console.log(b)
})

function example(myBool) {

  const item = "1"
  const key = "x"
  const cipFailedFlags = "y"


  const params = myBool ? {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  } : {}

  getInstance().updateItem(item, {
    ...params,
    [key]: cipFailedFlags
  })

}

example(true)
example(false)
```